# What's wrong with this block?

Tags: ios, animation, objective-c-blocks

I have a UIView called 'host' that contains lots of other views. Host is a subview of glView. Also host is an instance variable. So I have the following method:

```
-(void) doCancel:(id)sender {
    ANNOUNCE
    X.messageIsShowing = NO;
    CGFloat fadeOutTime = 0.4f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:fadeOutTime animations:^{ 
        host.alpha = 0.f; 
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [host removeFromSuperview];
        [host release];
    }];
}
```

It's supposed to fade out the host view and then remove it from its superview. It was working for a few weeks but now it's crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line '[host removeFromSuperview];'. I did change lots of stuff since it worked but nothing in this method so far as I know.

I added log statements so now it looks like this:

```
-(void) doCancel:(id)sender {
    ANNOUNCE
    X.messageIsShowing = NO;
    CGFloat fadeOutTime = 0.4f;
    CCLOG(@"host.alpha: %f", host.alpha);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:fadeOutTime animations:^{ 
        host.alpha = 0.f; 
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        CCLOG(@"host.alpha: %f", host.alpha);
        CCLOG(@"host %@", host);
        CCLOG(@"[host superview]: %@", [host superview]);
        [host removeFromSuperview];
        [host release];
    }];
}
```

All four log statements work and print what is expected. So 'host' and host's superview are valid for the log statements. But it still crashes on [host removeFromSuperview]. I also played around with lots of breakpoints. But debug commands don't work inside the completion block -- none of the ivars are in scope, probably because the completion block is running on Thread 1 instead of 0.  Can anybody tell me what's going on here?

Comment: `-removeFromSuperView` already calls release in the view in an MRC environment, there's no need for that extra release, especially because the view is now owned by the subview tree.

Comment: [host release] is required if you have retained it. E.g. a retained property.

Comment: host was created with an alloc and then added to glView. So removing it from glView (i.e., superview) still needs a release to balance the alloc. In fact I put in a log statement to show the retainCount just before [host removeFromSuperview] and it is 2.

Comment: I also put in a log statement to show the value of 'finished' inside the loop and it is 1 (i.e., YES).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `[host release]` inside the block. I'm guessing that `host` is an instance variable? (It does not seem to be a local variable.) If so, after you release it, you should set it to `nil`, like

```
[host release];
host = nil;
```

Otherwise, it may point to a deallocated object, and the next place that uses it will crash.

Comment: I'm giving this answer a check because it led me to fix the problem although I think the part about setting host to nil is irrelevant. But [host release] inside a completion block would probably never work. I put log statements everywhere I could think of trying to track exactly what was going on but it's still puzzling.

Comment: I'm giving a check to this because it led me to a line of thought that fixed the problem but I think setting host to nil is irrelevant. But [host release] inside a completion block is probably a bad idea as newacct said. With a lot more log statements I see that the retain count doesn't work as expected in the animation statement. E.g., it gets "mysteriously" incremented at the beginning of the method then gets decreased by 2 by [host removeFromSuperview]. I revised how host is allocated and inited and then I could remove [host release] from the completion block and the crash went away.

Comment: @RobertL: no, I didn't mean that having `[host release]` inside a block is problematic. (It is an instance variable of the object. You can release it when you are done with it.) It's just the releasing without setting it to `nil` that's problematic.

Comment: True. But not setting it to nil wasn't the cause this particular problem. host = nil; would have been good practice but in this case I never used host again so it didn't matter. [host release] caused the problem and by moving it somewhere else the problem got fixed.

Comment: @RobertL: The only way that `[host release]` causes a problem is if `host` points to an object that was already deallocated. I don't know what exactly you were doing differently about "how host is allocated and inited"; but, for example, if you didn't retain the object that `host` points to initially, that would explain it (objects pointed to by instance variables need to be retained, otherwise they may be deallocated when you try to use it next time); or, if you had done `[host release]` without setting it to nil elsewhere, that would also explain it.